# Incorrect moon value from Swiss Ephemeris

Tags: java

I am using Swiss Ephemeris jar file for calculating the planets values,ascendent value and i am getting correct values for every planet except moon value.
I know this question already been asked but they did't explain how to generate geocentric longitude to get the expected result. So can anyone explain how to generate geocentric longitude for the moon.
Link to the similar question 
[Swiss Ephemeris Sideral Mode with Lahiri Ayanamsha gives wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731142/swiss-ephemeris-sideral-mode-with-lahiri-ayanamsha-gives-wrong-values)

Link to the source code i am using from .
https://github.com/AaronNGray/AndroidSwissEphemerisExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/swissephemeris/swissephemeris/Chartdata.java

Comment: First thing to find out is if you're looking at Java or C#.

Comment: i am looking for java. Do you have any solution?